# can simpleperf record in loop just like systrace?

Tags: android

I encounter a problem, in this problem app's heap size increase rapidly.

I need use simpleperf to record what app does during the heap size increasing.

as we known, systrace command can capture trace event by ring buffer,  I can use --async-start command-line option to start tracing, when the problem occurs, I use --async-dump to capture last-happened trace.

However, I didn't found this feature in simpleperf tool,  how can I do the same thing like simpleperf?

Comment: I found solution, we can use perfetto tools to trace app by setting config with interval dumping heap profile.